# JAVA_HOME incorrectly set. How to reset it?

Tags: linux, maven, path, environment-variables, java-home

When I try to run `mvn` (Apache Maven, that is), I keep getting `error "JAVA_HOME" not set.`

I follow the instructions to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable as follow; In the terminal:

```
user@localhost$export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java

user@localhost$export PATH=$PATH:/home/usr/jdk1.7.0_02/bin
```

That looks correct, right? Then how come I still getting the incorrect `JAVA_HOME` error?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

JAVA_HOME typically should only include the folder that contains the bin folder.

So in your case

`export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdk1.7.0_02/`

`export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

In addition for finding the location of your java_home you can follow this command

```
which java
```

(This will return the path of the current java binary. Over here its /usr/bin/java)

`ls -alh /usr/bin/java`

( This will return true path to the symbolic link. Over here its /etc/alternatives/java.

`ls -alh /etc/alternatives/java`

( This will return true path to this symbolic link which is actual JAVA HOME path)

Answer (score 3):

1. Goto Terminal and open either of the following files using an editor of your choice (vim, nano, etc):

   ```
   # nano /etc/profile
   ```

   (or)

   ```
   # nano /root/.bash_profile
   ```

   (Instead of root you can also change your normal username.)
2. Now run the following commands:

   ```
   # export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.6.0"
   # export PATH="/opt/jdk1.6.0/bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. Logout and logon the system , now check the java version in your terminal using the following command:

   ```
   # java -version
   ```

   The output should look similar to this:

   ```
   # java -version
   java version “1.6.0″
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-b105)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.6.0-b105, mixed mode, sharing)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You could put the following in your .bashrc, then it should be correct even if you change to a different java.

```
a=`realpath /usr/bin/java`;
export JAVA_HOME="${a%/bin/java}"
```

Answer (score 1):

No... $JAVA_HOME must point to /home/user/jdk1.7.0_02/

To prevent errors like "/home/user" versus "/home/usr", $PATH should be "$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

And I recommend using a native package (yum, apt-get, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not what you set JAVA_HOME to.

http://maven.apache.org/download.html

> Make sure that JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_02 and that $JAVA_HOME/bin is in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` typically should only include the folder that contains the bin folder.

So set it as :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_02/

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

After that, you can also verify using :

```
which java
```